# Is IEEE 754 float arithmetic associative, commutative, distributive, etc? Why?

Tags: proof-techniques, arithmetic, floating-point

Does the associative/commutative/distributive/etc property hold for arithmetic performed with IEEE 754 floats?

Obviously the answer is no to most of those questions, but do any of the properties of standard arithmetic hold? How can one formulate proofs (or at least proof-like statements) explaining why any particular property does or does not hold?

Comment: A counterexample suffices to prove that a property doesn't hold (e.g., floats $x$, $y$ and $z$ such that $x+(y+z)\neq (x+y)+z$). As for proving that properties do hold, what are you looking for? A proof of $X$ is a convincing argument that $X$ is true. How one formulates a convincing argument that something is true depends very much on what that thing is. If you're asking for a proof or counterexample for each of the three-plus-etc properties, that's too much for a single question.

Answer (score 5):

The IEEE 754 standard defines exactly how floating-point arithmetic is performed. For many interesting theorems, you will need to examine the exact definition. For some less interesting ones, like a+b = b+a or ab = ba, all you need to know that IEEE 754 always calculates the exact result, rounded in a deterministic way. For non-theorems, like (a+b)+c = a+(b+c), which is false, all you need is a counterexample which is usually easy to find.

Answer (score -1):

Check e.g. [Goldberg's "What every computer scientist should know about floating point"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). Heavy reading, but a must.

Comment: I've read it. The only direct reference to the arithmetic axioms is a single sentence: "Due to roundoff errors, the associative laws of algebra do not necessarily hold for floating-point numbers." It later mentions "the importance of preserving parentheses". From this I've come to the conclusion that the reason why any axiom does or does not hold is down to whether or not it changes the order of operations. Is that more or less correct?

Comment: @tel, associative laws *don't* hold. Others do, like $x - x = 0$, $x + 0 = x$, $1 \cdot x = x$, $x + y = y + x$.

Comment: @vonbrand Interestingly, x + 0 = x doesn't hold if x is Not-a-Number because even though x + 0 is the same as x, it is not equal. On the other hand, x + 0 is not the same is x when x is a negative zero because x + 0 will be a positive zero. Then again, x - 0 _is_ always the same as x.

Comment: @gnasher729 Wow. So does that mean NaN - 0 == NaN?

Comment: @gnasher729 Let me see if I understand the rules behind your 3 statements:

1. NaN + 0 != NaN, because NaN + 0 is somehow implemented as a distinct entity wrt NaN.

2. -0 + 0 = 0, because that's just how they decided to handle that specific edge-case.

3. anything - 0 = anything, because - 0 is essentially treated as a noop.

My reasoning above is just my own inference, so please correct any of 1,2,3 if they're wrong